# Invert a dictionary inplace

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary with unique values and I want to invert it (i.e. swap keys with values) **inplace**. 
Is there any way doing it without using another dictionary?

I would prefer to just manipulate the items inside the dict than use a new dictionary, so that `id(my_dict)` would remain the same.

Comment: Python's `dict` is unordered. You should explain what you mean by reversing it.

Comment: Also, how do you think "inplace" should work? Is assignment of a new dictionary to an old dictionary variable is okay or do you want to just manipulate items inside the dict?

Comment: by reverse I mean swap keys-values, and I would prefer just manipulate the items inside the dict and not using a new dictionary, so the id(dict) would remain the same.

Comment: How would you inplace-swap a dict like `{1: 2, 2: 1}` without any auxiliary data structures?

Comment: What is {1:2, 2:2, 3:2} after the reversal?

Comment: @VPfB the values should be unique so there is no such case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to swap keys and values and do not mind duplicate values creating key conflicts, you can "reverse" the dictionary rather easily with a single line of code:

```
dictionary = dict(map(reversed, dictionary.items()))
```

If you would rather use the dictionary comprehension syntax instead, you can write this line:

```
dictionary = {value: key for key, value in dictionary.items()}
```

If you do not want to use the `items` method of the dictionary, it is rather easy to avoid:

```
dictionary = {dictionary[key]: key for key in dictionary}
```

If you can afford creating a copy of the dictionary, you can reverse it in place if needed:

```
def reverse_in_place(dictionary):
    reference = dictionary.copy()
    dictionary.clear()
    dictionary.update(map(reversed, reference.items()))
```

Comment: All of these create a new dict violating "without using another dictionary" requirement. I don't really see how swapping keys and values can be done in-place. @NogaKinor should probably elaborate the question before it can be answered.

Comment: I kinda like the last one, although I'd probably just do `reference = list(dictionary.items())`.

Comment: @NoctisSkytower The last one works just like I wanted. thanks!

Comment: @Kinor Thanks for the compliment! You may wish to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to continue encouraging people to answer your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to swap the keys and the values of the dict?

You can do it like this:

```
dict_name = dict(zip(dict_name.values(), dict_name.keys()))
```